# Dependent Picklists - Javascript callback

Tags: visualforce, javascript

**Situation**

Dependent Picklist fields are implemented in SFDC using a JS file called "Picklist.js". This script seems responsible for adding or removing `<select>` tags in visualforce pages.

**Question**

Is there a way to detect that a dependent picklist field was removed or added to the dom? I'm looking in particular for a callback-method or a javascript event.

Comment: Not realy correct question. By default a standard SFDC script  ensures that both dependent picklists are in sync and enabled/ disabled dependent list based on selected value of the controlling list. So there is no "removing".

Comment: Maybe you are right. But the sync is done by removing the physical "tag" and adding a new one. You can reproduce this behavior by adding a "style" to a dependent picklist e.g. color = red. After the controlling picklist has been changed the color attribute is removed. Therefore I assume that the node is removed and added.

Comment: OK, got it. But this is still a technical javascript question. You want to get an dom-changed-event for some element. I think you will need [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for that.

Comment: hmm. From a general point of view you are right. But maybe someone already solved this issue in the context of salesforce. I know that where are several events on "window" level which can be used to trigger custom javascript actions. But I'm not aware of dependent picklist events.

The problem is that there is no don-change-event. You had to implement such an event by yourself. And therefore you had to extend the existing javascript which doesn't seem very reliable..

Comment: Take a look http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion